# How do I actually calculate the Lorentz transformation of a field strength tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

Say now I have an arbitrary field strength tensor $F$, and I want to boost it according to a Lorentz transformation matrix $(\Lambda)$

The transformation is given by
$$
F^{'\mu \nu} =  \Lambda^{\mu}_{\;\alpha}  \Lambda^{\nu}_{\;\beta} F^{\alpha\beta}
$$

The question is, how do I actually calculate this with actual values?

Comment: First you have to find an explicit form for the matrix $\Lambda$.
I think the easiest way to do this is exponentiating a linear combination of the generators of Lorentz's Lie Algebra.
Then you just sum over the repeated indices, and you do that for each component of $F^{\mu\nu}$ that you would like to find.

Comment: If I have explicit matrix forms for both $\Lambda$ and $F^{\mu\nu}$ is there a nice rule of thumb or so to calculate $F^{'\mu\nu}$, $F^{'00} = \Lambda^0_{\; 0}\Lambda^0_{\; 0}F^{00} + .... $ is not only tedious but prone to silly mistakes

Comment: Can I ask why you need to exponentiate the generators of the Lie Algebra? I thought that was how spinors transform under Lorentz transformation. If you have an arbitrary tensor can't you just compose standard lorentz boost matrices?

Comment: WilliamGrunow, no. I don't think any shortcut exist, fora a general form of $\Lambda$.
@user82235, any element of the connected component to the identity of a Lie Group can be expressed as the exponential of a combination of generators of the algebra.
Of course, if you find it simpler, you can use the "standard lorentz boost matrices".
I personally prefer the other way, cause it allows me to remember by heart less things, and work out the same results. But either way is fine.

Comment: @Grunow: I agree with Carta that it is simply a tedious task, but it may be easier for you to think of it as matrix multiplication. Since:
$AB = \sum_{j} (A)_{ij}(B)_{jk}$ (where $(A)_{ij}$ is the elementh in the $i$th row and $j$th column of $A$)

In your example,
$F' = \Lambda F \Lambda^T$

Comment: @WilliamGrunow Is there a specific problem you want to do computations for?  While the general Lorentz transformation is tedious, often times a symmetry of the problem will reduce the amount of work needed considerably.

Comment: @Muphrid Well I was asking in general, but I routinely choose my coordinate such that $E$ and $B$ fields have componenents only in one direction and/or boost in only one spatial direction. Does that make the problem easier?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Important Note.**

As written, the transformation formula in the question is suppressing an important subtlety.  The field strength tensor is a tensor *field*; it is a function on spacetime.  As such, it's not just its indices that must transform under a Lorentz transformation, but also its argument.  The full transformation is as follows:
\begin{align}
  F'^{\mu\nu}(x') = \Lambda^\mu_{\phantom\mu\alpha}\Lambda^\nu_{\phantom\nu\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}(x), \qquad x' = \Lambda x
\end{align}
Or, put another way
\begin{align}
  F'^{\mu\nu}(x) = \Lambda^\mu_{\phantom\mu\alpha}\Lambda^\nu_{\phantom\nu\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}(\Lambda^{-1}x)
\end{align}
Authors often suppress this fact in the notation, but I found it confusing when I first learned the subject, so I think it's dangerous to not be explicit.

As a terminological aside, the transformation of the tensor indices is often referred to as a **target space transformation**  while the transformation of its argument is sometimes referred to as a **spacetime transformation**.

**Target space transformation - efficient computation**

An efficient way to compute an arbitrary target space transformation in this context is to note that when dealing with strings of contracted two-tensors, one can convert the expression into a sequence of matrix multiplications.

If we define matrices $\Lambda = (\Lambda^\mu_{\phantom\mu\nu})$ and $F = (F^{\mu\nu})$ where the left-most index is the "row" label and the right-most index is the "column" label, then we find that
\begin{align}
  \Lambda^\mu_{\phantom\mu\alpha}\Lambda^\nu_{\phantom\nu\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}
= \Lambda^\mu_{\phantom\mu\alpha}F^{\alpha\beta}\Lambda^\nu_{\phantom\nu\beta}
= (\Lambda F\Lambda^T)^{\mu\nu}
\end{align}
where the expression in parenthesis denotes successive matrix multiplication.

**Special Cases**

The matrix multiplication above is made significantly easier provided the Lorentz transformation one is performing is special.  In particular, suppose for instance that the Lorentz transformation is a boost along the $x$-direction.  Then the matrix $\Lambda$ will have the following block-matrix form
\begin{align}
  \Lambda = \begin{pmatrix}
    \lambda & 0 \\
    0 & I_2
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
  \lambda = \begin{pmatrix}
    \gamma & -\gamma\beta \\
    -\gamma \beta & \gamma
  \end{pmatrix}, \qquad
  I_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Therefore, if we write $F$ is 2-by-2 block matrix form;
\begin{align}
  F = \begin{pmatrix}
    f_{11} & f_{12} \\
    f_{12} & f_{22} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
then we have
\begin{align}
  F' &= 
\begin{pmatrix}
    \lambda & 0 \\
    0 & I_2
  \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    f_{11} & f_{12} \\
    f_{21} & f_{22} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    \lambda & 0 \\
    0 & I_2
  \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
  \lambda f_{11} & \lambda f_{12} \\
  f_{21} & f_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    \lambda & 0 \\
    0 & I_2
  \end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
  \lambda f_{11}\lambda & \lambda f_{12} \\
  f_{21}\lambda & f_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
so now one just needs do perform four 2-by-2 matrix multiplications, which is relatively easy.  Boosts in the $y$- and $z$- directions are similarly straightforward.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that it's meaningful to transform the EM field without transforming the argument, when the boost is not meant as a coordinate transformation.

Comment: @Muphrid Would you mind being more explicit about what context/example you have in mind?

Comment: The consideration of local Lorentz transformations as one would do when using tetrad formalism.

Comment: Hi Josh, there's a mistake here! I think you're forgetting $f_{11}$ must be a matrix. The correct result is $\{\{\lambda f_{11}\lambda,\lambda f_{12}\},\{ f_{21}\lambda,f_{22} \} \}$

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy Yes indeed! Thanks for catching my sloppiness!  Edited.

Answer (score 4):

For special relativity, you can use clifford algebra rotors to save some work over computing the matrix representation of a Lorentz boost.

Rotors in a clifford algebra are the 3+1 analogues of quaternions, and they're nearly as easy to use.  The big piece that you need to use them is the idea of clifford multiplication (also called the *geometric product*).

Let $e_t, e_x, e_y, e_z$ be basis vectors.  First, there's the metrical part of the geometric product.

$$e_t e_t = -1, \quad e_x e_x = +1, \quad e_y e_y = +1, \quad e_z e_z = +1$$

The signs, of course, are part and parcel to choosing a metric signature.

We've chosen an orthogonal basis here, in which the other products are very simple: they all anticommute.  Here, $a, b$ are *particular* indices (but it doesn't matter which indices they are).

$$e_a e_b = -e_b e_a$$

So $e_t e_x = -e_x e_t$, and so on.

Finally, the geometric product is associative, so an expression like $e_t e_x e_t$ can be manipulated as so:

$$e_t e_x e_t = e_t (e_x e_t) = -e_t (e_t e_x) = -(e_t e_t) e_x = + e_x$$

---

With the geometric product in place, we can begin to create *rotors*, our 3+1 analogues of quaternions.  Observe the following curious fact about the "bivector" $e_t e_x$:

$$(e_t e_x)^2 = e_t e_x e_t e_x = (+e_x) e_x = +1$$

So we have a nonscalar object that squares to +1.  Interesting.  What happens if we put that into an exponential using a power series?  Let $\phi$ be a scalar, and see that

$$\begin{align*}\exp(\phi e_t e_x) &= 1 + \phi e_t e_x + \frac{\phi^2}{2} (e_t e_x)^2 + \frac{\phi^3}{3!} (e_t e_x)^3 + \ldots \\ &= 1 + \frac{\phi^2}{2} + \ldots + e_t e_x (\phi + \frac{\phi^3}{3!} + \ldots)\\ &= \cosh \phi + e_t e_x \sinh \phi\end{align*}$$

This is a derivation of the Lorentz transformations, in terms of the rapidity $\phi = \tanh^{-1}(v/c)$.  An exercise for those at home:  try using the bivector $e_x e_y$ instead.  Show that $(e_x e_y)^2 = -1$, and thus the power series of the exponential $\exp(\theta e_x e_y) = \cos \theta + e_x e_y \sin \theta$.  This exponential approach emphasizes the similarities between boosts and rotations.

---

Now then, given a unit bivector $\hat B$ that describes the plane of rotation, and given a rapidity $\phi$, we can calculate a rotor $q$:

$$q = \exp(-\hat B \phi/2)$$

And we can use that rotor to rotate a vector $a$:

$$a' = q a q^{-1} = (\cosh \frac{\phi}{2} - \hat B \sinh \frac{\phi}{2}) a (\cosh \frac{\phi}{2} + \hat B \sinh \frac{\phi}{2})$$

Now, here's a fun trick:  the formula works for a bivector like the Faraday tensor $F$, also!  So you don't even have to rotate it twice the way you would have to do two matrix multiplies in index notation.